# Diophantine equation $x^{y} - y^{x}=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

I was thinking about the equation $x^{y} - y^{x}=1$ where $x,y \in \mathbb N$ and the solution $x=3$ and $y=2$ was easy to find. Also $x=2$ and $y=1$ is a solution.

I would like to know:

> Is this Diophantine equation studied somewhere and are there any other solutions known?

Comment: It is a particular case of [Mihailescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture), though not a particularly easy case.

Comment: Is this considered a Diophantine equation?

Comment: @AhmedHussein while most Diophantine equations are specifically polynomials where the exponents are known and the bases are unknown, there are several occurrences of seeking solutions to equations where the exponents are also unknowns or are instead the unknowns as well.  Often called exponential Diophantine equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x,y>1$ the only solution is $(x,y)=(3,2)$ by [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture). The remaining solutions are easily verified to be $(x,y)=(2,1)$ and $(x,y)=(x,0)$ for every $x>0$.